# Android application has stopped responding

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making a distance converter app.
The code compiles perfectly and runs too. But when i click on the button "Calculate" it says

> The application Converter(process com.example.converter) has stopped
>   unexpectedly.Please try again

The Logcat Screenshot:

The MainActivity.java code is :

```
package com.example.converter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // public var
    private EditText text;

    // default func
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // findViewById = Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute
        // from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
        // (EditText) = typecast
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    // default func
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Will be executed by clicking on the calculate button because we assigned
     * "calculate" to the "onClick" Property!
     */
    public void calculate(View view) {

        RadioButton mileButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton kmhButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        // if the text field is empty show the message "enter a valid number"
        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
            // Toast = focused floating view that will be shown over the main
            // application
            Toast.makeText(this, "enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            //parse input Value from Text Field
            double inputValue = Double.parseDouble(text.getText().toString());
            // convert to...
            if (mileButton.isChecked()) {
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToMiles(inputValue)));
                // uncheck "to miles" Button
                mileButton.setChecked(false);
                // check "to km/h" Button
                kmhButton.setChecked(true);
            } else { /* if kmhButton isChecked() */
                text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToKmh(inputValue)));
                // uncheck "to km/h" Button
                kmhButton.setChecked(false);
                // check "to miles" Button
                mileButton.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private double convertToMiles(double inputValue) {
        // convert km/h to miles
        return (inputValue * 1.609344);
    }

    private double convertToKmh(double inputValue) {
        // convert miles to km/h
        return (inputValue * 0.621372);
    }
}
```

Comment: we need the log cat...

Comment: I don't see the logcat screenshot. Please paste the stacktrace as *text*.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see at which point it throws this exception? Also why don't you also get the text view inside the calculate method instead of assigning it in the OnCreate() which seems wrong in itself.

Comment: Thats not what they meant by logcat lol. They meant the whole stacktrace from when the error occurred. But my guess is that `text` is null for whatever reason. A guess of course cuz we don't have the full logkittie stacktrace.

Comment: here's the link to the logcat: http://tinypic.com/r/aak56q/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code you are saying `calculate(View v)` while in XML (which is where I am assuming you have defined the onClick) you are saying `calc`. So basically change it to `calculate` and it should work.

Comment: Oh by the way, you can post the logcat on the post. Play with it to learn. Most of it is pretty obvious suprisingly enough. :)

Comment: wow!worked :) thx a lot @Andy !! sorry im a beginner